# Почему змейка не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

Помогите найти проблему змейки.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlock = width / blockSize;
var heightInBLock = height / blockSize;

var score = 0;

var drawBorder = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Gray';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
}

var drawScore = function() {
  ctx.font = '20px Courier';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Black';
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText('Score: ' + score, blockSize, blockSize)
}

var gameOver = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = '60px Courier';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Black';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText('Game Over', width / 2, height / 2);
}

var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.col = row;
}

Block.prototype.drawSquare = function(color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
}

Block.prototype.drawCircle = function(color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
}

Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
}

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(7, 5),
    new Block(6, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ]

  this.direction = 'right';
  this.nextDirection = 'right';
}

Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare('Blue');
  }
}

Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;
  this.direction = this.nextDirection;

  if (this.direction === 'right') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === 'down') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  } else if (this.direction === 'left') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === 'up') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
  }
  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
}

Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function(head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlock);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBLock);

  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

  var selfCollision = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true
    }
  }

  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
}

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === 'up' && newDirection === 'down') {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === 'rigth' && newDirection === 'left') {
    return
  } else if (this.direction === 'down' && newDirection === 'up') {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === 'left' && newDirection === 'right') {
    return;
  }

  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
}

var Apple = function() {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
}

Apple.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.position.drawCircle('LimeGreen');
}

Apple.prototype.move = function() {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlock - 2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBLock - 2)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
}

var snake = new Snake();
var apple = new Apple();

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
}, 100);

var directions = {
  37: 'left',
  38: 'up',
  39: 'right',
  40: 'down'
}

$('body').keydown(function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: не могли бы Вы уточнить, что именно не работает? П.С. ну и расписать, что делает та или иная функция

Comment: @Дмытрык пишет game over и все

Answer (score 0):

Банально опечатка:

```
var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.col = row; // this.row = row; !!!
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlock = width / blockSize;
var heightInBLock = height / blockSize;

var score = 0;

var drawBorder = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Gray';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
}

var drawScore = function() {
  ctx.font = '20px Courier';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Black';
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText('Score: ' + score, blockSize, blockSize)
}

var gameOver = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = '60px Courier';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Black';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText('Game Over', width / 2, height / 2);
}

var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
}

Block.prototype.drawSquare = function(color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
}

Block.prototype.drawCircle = function(color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
}

Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
}

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(7, 5),
    new Block(6, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ]

  this.direction = 'right';
  this.nextDirection = 'right';
}

Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare('blue');
  }
}

Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;
  this.direction = this.nextDirection;

  if (this.direction === 'right') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === 'down') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  } else if (this.direction === 'left') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === 'up') {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
  } else {
    console.warn(this.direction);
  }
  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
}

Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function(head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlock);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBLock);

  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

  var selfCollision = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true
    }
  }
  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
}

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === 'up' && newDirection === 'down') {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === 'rigth' && newDirection === 'left') {
    return
  } else if (this.direction === 'down' && newDirection === 'up') {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === 'left' && newDirection === 'right') {
    return;
  }

  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
}

var Apple = function() {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
}

Apple.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.position.drawCircle('LimeGreen');
}

Apple.prototype.move = function() {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlock - 2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBLock - 2)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
}

var snake = new Snake();
var apple = new Apple();

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawBorder();
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
}, 200);

var directions = {
  37: 'left',
  38: 'up',
  39: 'right',
  40: 'down'
}

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

PS:
Нафига вам jQuery?